# How to cast field type in sequelize, when use raw query?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

- MSSQL dialect
- in table I have a column with bigint type
- when I do a raw query like:

```
const product = {
  id: 1,
  isAvailable: true,
  lastUpdated:  4652082390 // epoch
};

await sequelize.query(`
                UPDATE Product SET
                    isAvailable = $isAvailable,
                    lastUpdated = $lastUpdated
                WHERE id = $id`,
                    {
                        bind: {
                            location: latlong,
                            isAvailable: isAvailable,
                            lastUpdated: lastUpdated,
                            id: product.id
                        }
                    }
                );
```

it fails with error:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: Validation failed for parameter 'lastUpdated'. Value must be between -2147483648 and 2147483647.

looks like it treat lastUpdated value as INTEGER, but not BIGINT :(

I tried cast value type as in shown in docs: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/raw-queries.html
but looks like this feature works only for Postgress which is not mine case

Answer (score 0):

```
await sequelize.query(`
                UPDATE Product SET
                    isAvailable = $isAvailable,
                    lastUpdated = cast($lastUpdated as int)
                WHERE id = $id`,
                    {
                        bind: {
                            location: latlong,
                            isAvailable: isAvailable,
                            lastUpdated: lastUpdated,
                            id: product.id
                        }
                    }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

`BIGINT` are a known issue with javascript (no real bigint).
The solution in sequelize (and any other DB npm for that matter) is to map BIGINT as strings.

In your case I will try following:

```
const product = {
  id: 1,
  isAvailable: true,
  lastUpdated:  '4652082390' // epoch
};
```